# dynamic table jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic-data

Hi I'm trying to have a dynamic table with different number of rows depends on the number of data how to do that can somebody show me ? I tried but my code only add one line I don't know how to make it to add different number of lines I have 2 types of data so in each row there is user name column and user address column.

```
$(document).ready( function(){
 $("#getdata").click(function () {
     var value1=$("#user_name").val();   
          $("#tr1").append(value1);    
var value2=$("#user_address").val();  
          $("#tr2").append(value2); 
           value1.append(value2)})})
```

I think what I need to do is figure out how the data number and set a loop in the tr but Iam not sure how to do that

Thank in advance 
LS

Comment: Can you use the code tag to format you code. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Where is your data coming from and why is it variable?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6Zqqp/).

Script

```
var $table  = $("#tblData");
var $userName = $("#userName");
var $userAddress = $("#userAddress");
$("#btnAdd").click(function(){
    $table.append("<tr><td>"+ $userName.val() +"</td><td>"+ $userAddress.val() +"</td></tr>")
    $userName.val("");
    $userAddress.val("");
});
```

You can add a validation to check whether both user name and address is entered by the user.